# зачем нужна проверка при #define?

Tags: c, define

В одной из книг встретил вот такую конструкцию

```
#if ! defined MANY || MANY < 1
#define MANY    10
#endif
```

хотя там можно обойтись только

```
#define MANY    10
```

дальше в программе MANY используется только как волшебное число. В других файлах оно тоже не переопределяется. Так зачем понадобилась проверка?

Книга [ООП для ANSI C](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf), страница под номером 5

Единственное, что приходит в голову - это не удалённый артефакт.

Comment: Это может быть include guard - защита от включения одного h-файла несколько раз, через другие h-файлы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой способ позволит создать некий набор "препроцессорных опций", имеющих значение по-умолчанию. Если написать просто `#define MANY 10`, то чтобы поменять это значение пользователю необходимо будет исправлять исходник. Если его не задать совсем, то пользователь будет обязан как-то определить этот макрос. Хотелось бы дать пользователю возможность настроить этот параметр самостоятельно, а если пользователь не желает этого делать, то использовать значение по-умолчанию.

```
//Если макрос MANY отсутствует, 
//либо его значение меньше единицы (ошибочное для кода из книги)
//то наделяем этот макрос неким дефолтным значением
#if ! defined MANY || MANY < 1
#define MANY    10
#endif
```

Теперь пользователь имеет возможность задать макрос `MANY` самостоятельно.
Например, есть возможность передать его значение в строке компиляции:

`gcc source.c -DMANY=13`

Теперь `MANY` представляет значение 13, и ветка с определением его как 10 будет пропущена.

Comment: Спасибо. О том, что так можно переопределять значения макросов я не знал.